# Killing assay analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I have a bacterial killing assay with 3 drug concentrations and one control. I have data for 6 time points including time point 0. I want to use statistical tests to compare the control to each treatment type to determine if there is a statistically significant difference at each time point. I'm not sure which tests to run. any help would be really appreciated.

I attached the data below

| Time | Control | Concentration 1 (1 X MIC) | Concentration 2 (10 X MIC) | Concentration 3 (25 X MIC) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T0 | 5.70E+06 | 4.60E+06 | 3.90E+06 | 3.50E+06 |
| T0 | 5.20E+06 | 5.10E+06 | 4.10E+06 | 4.30E+06 |
| T0 | 5.00E+06 | 4.80E+06 | 4.60E+06 | 4.40E+06 |
| T1 | 2.30E+07 | 4.30E+06 | 3.10E+06 | 1.70E+06 |
| T1 | 1.00E+07 | 5.30E+06 | 3.40E+06 | 4.40E+06 |
| T1 | 1.90E+07 | 4.90E+06 | 4.50E+06 | 4.10E+06 |
| T2 | 7.70E+07 | 1.20E+06 | 3.50E+06 | 2.20E+06 |
| T2 | 6.20E+07 | 9.00E+05 | 3.80E+06 | 1.20E+06 |
| T2 | 6.40E+07 | 6.00E+05 | 3.90E+06 | 2.20E+06 |
| T3 | 2.40E+08 | 2.30E+06 | 2.20E+06 | 1.10E+06 |
| T3 | 2.20E+08 | 2.20E+06 | 3.60E+06 | 1.50E+06 |
| T3 | 3.90E+08 | 2.80E+06 | 2.10E+06 | 2.20E+06 |
| T4 | 6.20E+08 | 1.60E+06 | 1.90E+06 | 8.30E+05 |
| T4 | 8.40E+08 | 1.30E+06 | 2.30E+06 | 6.90E+05 |
| T4 | 8.90E+08 | 1.40E+06 | 3.00E+06 | 7.40E+05 |
| T5 | 7.70E+08 | 5.00E+05 | 4.50E+05 | 2.20E+05 |
| T5 | 8.60E+08 | 1.20E+06 | 4.00E+05 | 5.30E+05 |
| T5 | 1.04E+09 | 6.00E+05 | 7.70E+05 | 5.20E+05 |

--------Edit--------------

each concentration of drug has 3 repeats (ex the 3 T0's )
the data for each concentration shows the number of CFU/mL recovered at each time point (T0-T5).

MIC is the minimum inhibitory concentration (the minimum amount of antibiotic needed to prevent visible bacterial growth) so in this experiment, one culture with untreated bacteria was used, 1 X the MIC bacterial culture, 10 X MIC bacterial culture and 25 X MIC bacterial culture.

I'm wanting to compare the CFU/mL (3 repeats) of each antibiotic treatment with CFU/mL of the control individually at each time point to determine statistical difference from the control (untreated bacteria)

Comment: You probably need a model, a mixed effects model. Can you share your data?

Comment: ... or else you need a dose-response model.  What is your biological endpoint or response?  Counts of deaths and survivors?

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, i added the data to my answer.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, I solely ended my experiment after the 6 hour time point, but my goal was to consider bacterial reduction and identify persister cells within the different treatment groups at 1 hour incriments from the addition of antibiotics.

Comment: Please explain what the columns mean.

Comment: apologise i shall amend the column names M1 M10 and M25 are the different concentrations which I used with M being the minimum inhibitory concentration. So I used 1 X the bacterial MIC 10 X the bacterial MIC and 25 X the bacterial MIC

Comment: If these are concentrations of doses, then where in this table are the *responses?*  From these numbers alone it is difficult, if not impossible, to figure out what your experiment was.  You need to include a description in your post.

Comment: So the columns represent the different treatments (drug concentration levels), for each treatment ['Untreated' (control), 'M1', 'M10', 'M25'] I took 3 readings of bacteria count (ex the 3 T0's). I am aiming to find whether there is a significant difference between the treatments at each of the 5 time points. I think I have to use t0 as a baseline as the starting amounts of bacteria differed but am confused how to continue.

Comment: For example, at time point 0 the bacteria count for the control (0 concentration) was 5.7e6 and the bacteria count for the first concentration (1%) was 4.6e6. I will edit the post to make this clear.

Comment: Do you really need a model for this?  A plot of the data shows a clear difference between test and control; counts decrease in the treatment groups and increase in the control, no model needed.  A more salient question for modelling might be if there are differences between concentrations.

Comment: @Demetri Good points.  With such large imprecise counts I suspect they aren't true counts but have been based on some other measurement (perhaps a count within a small window in a slide, scaled up by a huge factor).  That could make a difference in how one assesses the (statistical) significance of the apparent trends.

Comment: @DemetriPananos yes you are right these counts were taken on diluted culture which I then multiplied by dilution level and converted to the correct unit. I'm thinking of just performing some basic statistical tests, which in part is why I performed the test in triplicate. I was thinking of doing multiple t-tests for analysis at each point but was unsure if this would be the best approach. that is good point about inter-concentration comparisons

Comment: @Jamie Before we can comment on statistical hypotheses, we need to know a few things: 1) What is the hypothesis?  Clearly, no statistics are needed if the comparator is control.  Is your hypothesis about the between concentration effectiveness?  And if so, what is that hypothesis specifically as it relates to time? 2) How were the data collected?  Whuber notes that these counts are large and imprecise.  Can you explain how the data were collected?

Comment: For statistical tests It's typically best to work close to the original observations. In this case, that would be the actual colony counts (and the associated dilution levels, if they differed among the cultures). Could you please add that information to the data table? As others have noted, you don't need statistical tests in this instance to say that all treatments differed from control from 1 hour on. Would you like to learn how to test for differences among the treatments, too? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.